# Replace image set through content property and show another image on hover

Tags: css, image, pseudo-element

I am trying to replace an image which is been set through content property and replacement of image should be done on hover.

The image which I want to replace is displayed now by replacing the system default menu item. Here is the code by which I had replaced default menu item:

```css
.admin__menu .level-0.item-megamenu > a:before  {
    content: url('../images/list.svg');
    position: relative;
    top:-7px;
    color: #f7f3eb;
}
```

Now I want to replace this list.svg with another image on hover.
I tried replacing list.svg with the `background-image` property which is partially successful as it doesn't completely replace list.svg.

Here is the image of which I want to be replaced on hover:

[image: Menu item]

Can please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like all you need to do is set a new `content` value under a hover rule for whatever parent you want to trigger the new image. My example shows the user hovering on `.item-megamenu`. You may be putting `:hover` in the wrong spot? Didn't see it in your code.

```
.admin__menu .level-0.item-megamenu:hover > a:before  { /* Declare hover in selector */
content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzFyG.png'); /* Link to new image */
```